# Playing Notification Sound with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have this `script` to get new messages from my `database`

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_chat.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".msg_area").html(response);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

I am try to add a sound to it as soon as new data is added to the `database` but when i add to the `script` above, it plays the `audio` every `2 seconds`(i think this is because its in the `setInterval`)

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_chat.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".msg_area").html(response);
                var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

So please i ask. How do i play sounds only when a new data has been added to the database?

Comment: is every time `response` is coming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cache the last `response` and compare it with the new version to determine whether or not to play the audio file.

```js
var lastResponse = ''

setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_chat.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
      $(".msg_area").html(response)
      if (lastResponse && response !== lastResponse) {
        var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3')
        audio.play()
      }
      lastResponse = response
    }
  });
}, 2000);
```

Edit: If you want audio to play the first time a `response` comes in, remove `lastResponse &&` from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , sure it plays every 2s because of `setInterval()`

You need to compare num of messages rows in your database before response and after.. for me the simple thing is to pass it inside hidden `<div>` in your last message

```
setInterval(function () {
        var message_num = // get the number from the last message
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_chat.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".msg_area").html(response);
                var new_message_num = // get the number from the last message after response
                if(new_message_num > message_num){
                  var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
                  audio.play();
                }
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: how about to use it in firefox ? it shows a warning without playing a sound.
```Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted.```